# how to multiple explode?

Tags: php, arrays

I Need To separate First `@` , second `,` this Variable
[image]

```
$str = '1000,10.00,10000.00@500,5.00,2500.0';


$ex = explode('@',$str);
 //result = Array ( [0] => 1000,10.00,10000.00 [1] => 500,5.00,2500.00 );

  $ex2 = explode(',',$ex);
 //result need Array ( [0] => 1000, [1] => 500, [2] => 2500);
```

Comment: May be `list($ex1, $ex2) = explode('@', $str);` - then explode `$ex1`, `$ex2`.

Comment: [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array, so `$ex` will be an array that you need to iterate/[foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over

Comment: You should not use `print_r()` in an assignment as it will normally just return true.

Comment: can you plz explain?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you've already received some output, what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
<?php
$str = '1000,10.00,10000.00@500,5.00,2500.0';
$arrayResult = [];
$arrayData = explode('@',$str);
foreach($arrayData as $sing){
    $arrayResult[] = explode(",",$sing);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayResult);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` returns an array, so `$ex` will be an array that you need to iterate/foreach over:

```
<?php
// Init array to hold exploded values
$exploded = [];
$str = '1000,10.00,10000.00@500,5.00,2500.0';

$ex = explode('@',$str);

// Iterate over the $ex-exploded items
foreach ( $ex as $exItem ) {
  // Add items to the $exploded array
  array_push($exploded, explode(',', $exItem));    
}

print_r($exploded);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 10.00
            [2] => 10000.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 5.00
            [2] => 2500.0
        )

)
```

**Edit:**
If you want all values in one array you could

```
$exploded = array_merge($exploded[0], $exploded[1]);
print_r($exploded);
```

which will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 10.00
    [2] => 10000.00
    [3] => 500
    [4] => 5.00
    [5] => 2500.0
)
```